# Sqlite dependency with etherpad-lite

Tags: node.js, sqlite

I'm trying to get etherpad-lite to work with sqlite. When I run it with that setting I get this handy error message

> [2015-12-10 15:52:53.162] [ERROR] console - FATAL: The sqlite
>   dependency could not be loaded. We removed it from the dependencies
>   since it caused problems on several Platforms to compile it. If you
>   still want to use sqlite, do a 'npm install sqlite3' in your
>   etherpad-lite root folder

However after following the instructions, and seeing the sqlite3 files get installed in the node_modules directory, I still get the same error message.

I'm at a loss at what to troubleshoot next. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out that the sqlite3 module was not working. I needed to install an alternative arch

**Installing an alternative arch**

> To request an (additional) arch be installed that is different from
>   the value of process.arch for your running node version you can pass
>   --target_arch. For example, to install a 32bit binary on the 64 bit system do:

```
npm install sqlite3 --target_arch=ia32
```

https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/wiki/Binaries#installing-an-alternative-arch